# What happens if you put too much oil into a reciprocating engine wet sump?

Tags: engine, piston-engine, airplane

Apparently putting too much oil into your airplane engine is really bad and can be expensive but why? Will the excess oil go out via the oil breather,... ? Thank you

Comment: Same reason as car engines -   https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/what-actually-happens-when-there-is-way-too-much-oil-in-a-car-engine

Comment: Nothing bad happens. It just blows out all over your belly. For example, my Cessna 210 maintenance manual says to add 10 qts of oil when you do an oil change. If we do that 1/2 qt goes to the filter and 1 1/2 qts get blown overboard on the first flight. So we add 8 qts and then keep it at 6-7 quarts after the first flight.